# Permgen space incremental filling/resizing. How to fine tune avoid resizing of it

Tags: java, memory-management, low-level, permgen

Default permgen space is 64MB (as per sun docs) and it actually grows up to 83MB (confirmed using verbose GC). 
I ran into an issue where permgen space would not go out of memory but will remain at close to max available at that time.

So, my question is how does permgen space increase? Incrementally as more classes are loaded up to max default of 64MB/83MB?

It seems permgen is trying to resize itself on the fly, as more space is required. If so, can by allotting `-XX:MaxPermSize` to a value avoid permgen space resizing?

Comment: Thx for suggestion, but, cant.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is to use -xx:Permsize=n. So it grows incrementally until it reaches its max just like other spaces on jvm heap. If XX:MaxPermSize=n then incremental growth will not happen,thus avoiding resizing.